# Identify port on old Nokia flip phone

Tags: mobile-phone

It's an old 2007 [**Nokia 2760 flip phone**](https://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_2760-1975.php).

What port is this? I have searched everywhere but can't find any info. If this is a USB port, what USB plug it receives, or if something else…?

[image]

The official manual simply ignores that port

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a port for the Nokia [**CA-50**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Nokia+Connectivity+Cable+ca-50&) USB data connectivity cable. Used by phone models 1200, 2600, 2650, 2680, 2760, 1650.

[image]